# animate a div and expand from center

Tags: css, animation, center, expand

I have a simple code that expands a div horizontal and vertically from center,
but it only expands to the left or to the bottom, I want it expands to both side(left=50px, right=50px) or (top=50px, bottom=50px) from center with total equal to 100px.
here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div {
    background-color:#bca;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:10px;
}
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>

<div id="block">Hello!</div>
<script>


$("#go").click(function(){
  $("#block").animate({
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    opacity: 0.6,
  }, 1500 );
});
</script>

</body>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

How's this?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
    <div id="block">Hello!</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background-color:#bca;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    $("#block").animate({
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        top: "-50px",
        left: "-50px",
        opacity: 0.6,
    }, 1500 );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/theguywholikeslinux/87f4Y/

I used margin-left and margin-top for the centering and animated the top: and left: values to make the box grow up and left as well as down and right.

You may have to add some extra CSS if you want the "Hello" to stay in the center of the box as well.

Comment: Wow That's cool, this is all I want it! Thank you, you saved my day~

Comment: @vike if you press the tick button next to the up and down arrows then you can mark my answer as 'accepted' and everyone will know that your problem has been solved and what the solution was.

Comment: Amazing. As of 2022, no need to see jQuery for this too; animate is supported by the Web API, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59341498/13078832)