# jQuery: How to toggle a round div, and start toggle from center? (Expand from center)

Tags: jquery, toggle, effect, pageload

Language: **Javascript** | **jQuery** | **PHP** | **HTML5**

What I'm asking for is similar to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675491/animate-a-div-and-expand-from-center).

I need to grow a "bubble" (round thingy) **from the center (and not from top-left)**, on first page load.

I am able to accomplish this using **negative margins**, **[demo of what I have so far](http://likebam.com/test/test.php)**.

Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.bubble').animate({
opacity: 1,
width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
margin: '-25%'
  }, 800, function() {
```

But the thing is, I am using this alongside a "hover" effect which (on hover) should expand the bubbles to 10%, from the middle as well. JS found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208118/1399030)**.

Now, the negative margin from the initial page load is set to -25% because that's the only way to center it, but the hover effect uses the margins from the div's CSS which is not inline with the -25% margin that was initially loaded.

What I'm trying to accomplish is exactly how it is done on this page: https://www.vizify.com/rand-fishkin

- Bubbles are initially loaded on page load (expand from the center)
- Bubbles grow on hover (expand from the center by 10% of current size)

I am clueless right now, how do I make this work? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, by placing the 2nd snippet of code **inside** as callback (after the bubbles are loaded).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// LOAD BUBBLES

    $('.bubble').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    margin: '-25%'
  }, 400, function() {


// NOW, LOAD HOVER EFFECTS

        $(".bubble").on('scale', function(e, s) {
            var data = $.data(this, 'size'),
                w = data.width,
                h = data.height;
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width: w * s,
                height: h * s,
                marginLeft: data.marginLeft - w * (s-1) / 2,
                marginTop: data.marginTop - h * (s-1) / 2
            });
        }).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.data(this, 'size', {
                width: $this.width(),
                height: $this.height(),
                marginLeft: parseInt($this.css('margin-left')),
                marginTop: parseInt($this.css('margin-top'))
            });
        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).trigger('scale', [1.2])
        }, function() {
            $(this).trigger('scale', [1.0])

        });


    });
});
```