# Ionic 4 keyboard covers input field

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app that has a form with inputs in it.
When the user clicks on the input, it opens the keyboard, but it hides the content, without scrolling.
Is there any way around this?

This is my code:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendMail()">
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="floating">name
     </ion-label>
     <ion-input [(ngModel)]="senderName">
     </ion-input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">mail
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="senderMail">
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="borderedTextArea">
      <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="mailText" style="height:150px;"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-button type="submit" style="float:left">send</ion-button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm currently using Ionic4 with Cordova 9 and all the latest packages, and I could not find any settings within the framework that worked for me. In the end I made this workaround that completely circumvents the framework. It has a little animation and looks pretty OK, so I'm using it until the framework solves this properly.

import * as $ from "jquery";

global.scss

```
ion-app {
    /*animation of native keyboard show*/
    transition: margin 300ms;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
declare var $: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // This element never changes.
    let ionapp = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-app")[0];

    window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', async (event) => {
        // Move ion-app up, to give room for keyboard
        let kbHeight: number = event["keyboardHeight"];
        let viewportHeight: number = $(window).height();
        let inputFieldOffsetFromBottomViewPort: number = viewportHeight - $(':focus')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
        let inputScrollPixels = kbHeight - inputFieldOffsetFromBottomViewPort;

        // Set margin to give space for native keyboard.
        ionapp.style["margin-bottom"] = kbHeight.toString() + "px";

        // But this diminishes ion-content and may hide the input field...
        if (inputScrollPixels > 0) {
            // ...so, get the ionScroll element from ion-content and scroll correspondingly
            // The current ion-content element is always the last. If there are tabs or other hidden ion-content elements, they will go above.
            let ionScroll = await $("ion-content").last()[0].getScrollElement();
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(ionScroll).animate({
                    scrollTop: ionScroll.scrollTop + inputScrollPixels
                }, 300);
            }, 300); // Matches scroll animation from css.
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
        // Move ion-app down again
        // Scroll not necessary.
        ionapp.style["margin-bottom"] = "0px";
    });
}
```

Comment: can we use vanilla javascript instead of jQuery for the animate() function?

Comment: Yes, e.g. there is an answer on the subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521081/jquery-animate-function-equivalent-in-pure-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I was having that issue too but only in android, what i did was to create a script that get the height of the focused element and the keyboard, and using jQuery I added a marginTop to move the body above the keyboard when the keyboard shows, this is my code:

```
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private keyboard: Keyboard
  ) {
    if(this.platform.is('android')){
      this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe((e) => {
        const offset = $(document.activeElement).offset().top;
        let height = (offset - e.keyboardHeight)*-1;
        height = height > 0 ? 0 : height;      
        $('body').animate({ 'marginTop': height + 'px' }, 100);
      });
      this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(e => {
        $('body').animate({ 'marginTop': 0 + 'px' }, 100);
      });
    }
}
```

libs needed:

```
    npm install jquery
    npm install @types/jquery
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
    npm install @ionic-native/keyboard
```

imports

```
    import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
    import * as $ from "jquery";
    import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';
```

Is not an elegant solution but it works

Just some change in this code will give better experience

```js
this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe((e) => {
    const safeArea = 40 ;
    const offset1 = $(document.activeElement).offset().top;
    const offset2 = window.innerHeight - e.keyboardHeight - $(document.activeElement).height() - safeArea ;
    const diff = offset1 - offset2;
    if(offset1 > window.innerHeight -  e.keyboardHeight - safeArea)
        $('body').animate({ 'marginTop': -1 * diff + 'px' }, 100);
});
```

[image]

Comment: upvoted for effort

Answer (score 1):

```
<preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="true" />
```

You can install cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard and edit your config.xml file and add this line of code

[cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard)

> There is an Android bug that prevents the keyboard from resizing the WebView when the app is in full screen (i.e. if StatusBar plugin is used to hide the StatusBar). This setting, if set to true, add a workaround that resizes the WebView even when the app is in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this Ionic bug provisionally with:

```
...
<ion-texarea (ionFocus)="fixTextareaBug()">
...
```

and in your .ts

```
@ViewChild(IonTextarea)
public ionTextArea: IonTextarea;
private focusFix = false;

...
...

public fixTextareaBug() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.focusFix) {
      this.focusFix = false;
      return;
    }
    (this.ionTextArea as any).el.lastElementChild.blur();
    this.focusFix = true;
    (this.ionTextArea as any).el.lastElementChild.focus();
  }, TEXTAREA_TIMEOUT);
}
```

I hope it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I solve that by downgrading the keyboard plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard@2.0.5
```

and then remove the android platform and add it again

Answer (score 0):

Simply solve it with ionFocus event and scrollToBottom fuction and then call it in ionFocus so when you focus in input your content will scroll to bottom**strong text**

Comment: html.
          <ion-input clear-on-edit="true" placeholder="Type your message" [(ngModel)]="msg" type="text" (ionFocus)="showOptionsToggle(true)"></ion-input>


ts.

 @ViewChild(IonContent, {read: IonContent, static: false}) myContent: IonContent;  

ScrollToBottom() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myContent.scrollToBottom(300);
    }, 1000);
  }

  showOptionsToggle(boo) {
    console.log('True or false:-', boo);
    this.ScrollToBottom();
  }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to add additional information . Don't use comments to post large pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

you could try some combination of

```
ionFocus
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#events and

```
scrollIntoView
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView
if nothing else is working

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29852078)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me to show the input box just over the keyboard. I am using Ionic 7 with react.

Using `IonFooter` achieves that the content is at the bottom and not hidden. Using `IonModal` with height equal to 'auto' achieves that the modal is just as tall as its content.

Important: You must add the following line to `variables.css` so that the modal has an auto height.

```css
ion-modal.auto-height {
  --height: auto;
}
```

The example component:

```
export const TestPage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <IonContent>
        <IonText><h2>Content area</h2></IonText>
      </IonContent>
      {/* Added green background to make the footer/modal area visible for this example. */}
      <IonFooter style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <IonButton id="open-custom-dialog" fill='clear'>
          <IonLabel>Open modal</IonLabel>
        </IonButton>
        <IonModal
          breakpoints={[0, 1]}
          initialBreakpoint={1}
          handle={false}
          trigger="open-custom-dialog"
          className='auto-height'>
          <IonList>
            <IonItem>
              <IonInput
                label="Your input"
                placeholder="Type here"/>
            </IonItem>
          </IonList>
        </IonModal>
      </IonFooter>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**WorkAround**
I haven't found a solution, but I discovered a workaround for the ion-input being covered by the keyboard problem, I just gave the ion-input a pointer-events:none;

```
ion-input{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This solved the issue for me