# How to smooth scroll two elements at the same time using scrollIntoView()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to smooth scroll two divs at the same time using scrollIntoView(). I have tried these two ways, but only the last div called scrolls:

Attempt 1: function with two parameters: only the second parameter scrolls

```
function precedent_scroll(link, section) {
  document.getElementById(link).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

Attempt 2: calling function back to back: only "section2_IDname" scrolls

```
function precedent_scroll(section) {
  document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}

$("#id").click(function() {precedent_scroll("section1_IDname"), precedent_scroll("section2_IDname")});
```

Is this possible with only using scrollIntoView()?

Comment: Would need a setTimeout in there if objective is to scroll to one, let user see it for specific time, then scroll to other

Comment: @charlietfl that's what I'm using currently as a stand-in solution, but is there a way to do both simultaneously with scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"}) (or something with a similar animation)?

Comment: Not built in ... no. Could use jQuery animate with delay() but it would require your  own position calcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with jQuery:

```
function double_scroll(id1, id2) {
  var id1_parent_st = $([id1 parent]).scrollTop();
  var id2_parent_st = $([id2 parent]).scrollTop();
  $([id1 parent]).animate({
    scrollTop: $(id1).position().top + id1_parent_st
  }, 500, function(){
  });
  $([id2 parent]).animate({
    scrollTop: $(id2).position().top + id2_parent_st
  }, 500, function(){
  });
}

$([div]).click(function() {double_scroll("#p1_link", "#p1_section")});
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this without Jquery?

Comment: @NahushFarkande I'm sure if you just look up how to translate parts of the code to pure JS, it'll work. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521081/jquery-animate-function-equivalent-in-pure-javascript